# Git Partial Fork, synced pull/merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull

I want to fork a Git repository **A** that works with interface **X**, to my own repository **B** that works with interface **Y**.

To do this I would remove **X**-related files and create my own **Y**-related files, however I want to be able to pull changes to the core from repository **A**, in to my repository **B**, without pulling in **X**-related files (that I've already removed) and I want to be able to submit changes (i.e. pull request) I've made to the core, without that pull, removing **X** files from **A** or adding **Y** files to **A**.

From looking through similar questions on this site I've found things like rebasing, and selective merge, I'm not sure if this is actually what I want or not.

My main concern is keeping track of who made what changes, but I also would like to keep the relationship between the to projects if possible.

P.S. both projects are on github, if that provides any extra options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you describe, you cannot merge between **A** and **B**. You could instead create an in-between branch **A'**:

- Merge **A** into **A'** to obtain upstream changes.
- Commit shared changes to **A'**.
- Merge **A'** into **B** to apply these changes to your **Y**-specific code.
- Commit **Y**-specific changes to **B**
- Never merge **B** into **A'**.
- If you have changes in **B** that you want to share with **A**, cherry-pick them into **A'**.
- Request pulls to **A** from **A'** to share your changes upstream.

Other possible solutions include supporting both **X** and **Y** in both **A** and **B**, or splitting **X** and **Y** support into separate repositories.

Comment: With this method, would A' contain X? I assuming it would.

Comment: Yes, A' would contain X.